# get current focused window id using objective c

Tags: objective-c, window

how can i get current focused window id using objective c, the return value should be an int, help is highly appreciated! I just need to get the following line working

```
CGImageRef windowImage = CGWindowListCreateImage(CGRectNull, kCGWindowListOptionIncludingWindow, winNum, kCGWindowImageBoundsIgnoreFraming);
```

but no matter which window that i focus at, winNum is always 0.

Answer (score 7):

```
NSWindow *keyTarget = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
NSInteger winNum = [keyTarget windowNumber];
```

or in one line:

```
[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] windowNumber];
```